# CMake can't find non-default Eigen installation

Tags: cmake, eigen

I'm on Lubuntu 20.04. I have `libeigen3-dev`installed with apt, which is version 3.3.7. However, for a project, I need 3.4.0.

I downloaded Eigen in a separate folder under `$HOME/Libs/eigen-3.4.0`, and I'm trying to get CMake to find it. I am using:

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.4.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

However, CMake seems to be only able to find the systemwide install, and constantly complains that it cannot fulfill the version requirement. I have tried all combinations I could of both `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `Eigen3_DIR` to no avail.

How exactly should I call CMake to make it see the folder in my home?

Comment: While Eigen could be used without installation, using it via `find_package` **requires installation**. Among other things, this installation produces the script `Eigen3Config.cmake`, which is used by `find_package`. You may install Eigen into the custom directory, and set variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` pointing to that directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, I was indeed missing the build step, it was not clear from the instructions that it was needed :)